# eval not printing "Hello World" and still outputs to stderr

Tags: perl, dbi

I would like Perl or DBI to not send error exceptions when there is an error connecting to a database. My objective is once I cannot connect to the database either by username/password or URL issues, to send code to my monitoring server.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dsn = 'DBI:ODBC:Driver={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1}';
my $host = 'whatever.com,1433';
my $database = 'xxxxx';
my $user = 'xxxxx';
my $auth = 'xxxxxxx';

eval {
my $dbh = DBI->connect("$dsn;Server=$host;Database=$database",
$user,
$auth);
};


if ($@) {
  print "Hello World.\n";
  ## Eventually, I'll put code here to send alerts to the monitoring server
}
```

Even using eval, Perl/DBI still outputs the error and it doesn't print "Hello World".

```
DBI connect('Driver={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql- 
17.5.so.2.1};Server=xxxxx- 
xxxxxxx.com,1433;Database=xxxxxx','xxxxuser1',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 
17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xxxxuser1'. (SQL-28000) at ./x.pl 
line 14.
```

Comment: Pass this fourth param to `connect`: `{ PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1 }`  (Can't write a full answer right now)

Comment: @ikegami worked, please print full answer so you can get credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, DBI methods print an error message to STDERR and return false on error.

To enable throwing an exception on error, use the following option:

```
RaiseError => 1
```

To disable printing to STDERR, use the following option:

```
PrintError => 0
```

(This doesn't stop uncaught exceptions from being output to STDERR.)

This is what it looks like:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
   "$dsn;Server=$host;Database=$database",
   $user, $auth,
   { PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1 },
);
```